# ppt paste from excel clipboard to slide

Tags: excel, vba

I have a chart range copied from excel. Now I want to paste it as picture in slide 5 of active presentation, but it is giving me below error.

"Shapes(unknown member):Invalid request.Clipboard is empty or contains data which may not be pasted here."

Please help, code below.

```
Sub UpdateCharts()
Dim oPP As PowerPoint.Slide
Dim shp As PowerPoint.shape
ActivePresentation.Slides(5).Shapes.Paste
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the code below (explanation inside the code comments):

```
Option Explicit

'=====================================================================
' This sub exports a range from Excel to PowerPoint,
' pastes it, and later on modifies it's position and size (if needed)
' The code works using Late-Binding, so there's no need
' to add References to the VB Project
'=====================================================================

Sub UpdateCharts()

Dim ppApp                               As Object
Dim ppPres                              As Object
Dim ppSlide                             As Object
Dim ppShape                             As Object

' check if PowerPoint application is Open
On Error Resume Next
Set ppApp = GetObject(, "PowerPoint.Application")
On Error GoTo 0

If ppApp Is Nothing Then
    MsgBox "PowerPoint Application is not open", vbCritical
    Exit Sub
End If    

' set the Active Presentation
Set ppPres = ppApp.ActivePresentation

' set the Slide
Set ppSlide = ppPres.Slides(5)

' --- copy the Chart's Range (from Excel) ---
' <-- put your copy section here, right before the Paste
'With Worksheets("toPPT")            
'    .Range("F6:J7").Copy
'End With

' --- Paste to PowerPoint and modify properties (if needed) ---
Set ppShape = ppSlide.Shapes.PasteSpecial(3, msoFalse) ' 3 = ppPasteMetafilePicture
' modify properties of the pasted Chart (if needed)
With ppShape
    .Left = 535
    .Top = 86
End With
Application.CutCopyMode = False

ppPres.Save

Set ppSlide = Nothing
Set ppPres = Nothing
Set ppApp = Nothing

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
  mySlide.Shapes.PasteSpecial DataType:=2  '2 = ppPasteEnhancedMetafile
  Set myShape = mySlide.Shapes(mySlide.Shapes.(5))
```